# Can I safely delete the 'macOS' folder generated by 'flutter create'?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

Whenever I run `flutter create my_app_name` it generates a number of folders (such as 'lib', 'ios', 'android', 'build') which in my case I do need.

Since I'm just interested in developing (mobile) apps for both iOS and Android, there are also some other folders automatically created which I believe I don't necessarily need.

I was wondering if I could safely delete from 'my_app_name' the 'macos' and 'web' folders. And also if it would be a good practice to maybe remove other folders that for mobile development would result in being useless, without affecting the compiling process of course.

Comment: if you don't develop app for macOS or web platform, You can delete with no problem